# Mapping Google Spreadsheets json response to java object returns error message

Tags: java, json

I am getting the following JSON output:

```
{
  "range": "Frontpage!E6:E15",
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": [
    [
      "FundRequest"
    ],
    [
      "nOS"
    ],
    [
      "NEX"
    ],
    [
      "DREP"
    ],
    [
      "ChromaWay"
    ],
    [
      "Jura"
    ],
    [
      "Origo"
    ],
    [
      "Phantasma"
    ],
    [
      "NuCypher"
    ],
    [
      "Oasis Labs"
    ]
  ]
}
```

So I created the following wrapper:

```
public class Wrapper {

     private String range;
     private String majorDimension;
     private List<String> values;

     // getters and setters

}
```

Now I want use `GsonBuilder` to map the JSON to my object:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Wrapper w = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Wrapper.class);
```

but I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 37 path $.values[0]
```

How do I fix it? Is there any way for me to convert it from a `List<List<String>>`to a `List<String>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, You should use List `List<<List<String>>` instead of `List<String>` for values.

second, You can get `List<String>` from `List<List<String>>` Using below code,

```
public <T> List<T> flattenListOfListsImperatively(
    List<List<T>> nestedList) {
    List<T> ls = new ArrayList<>();
    nestedList.forEach(ls::addAll);
    return ls;
}
```

or using Java-8

```
public <T> List<T> flattenListOfListsStream(List<List<T>> list) {
    return list.stream()
      .flatMap(Collection::stream)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());    
}
```

Also, do a search in GSON is there any built-in way to flatten the nested collection. Please post it here if there is anything.

Edit 1: I did a quick search in GSON library and it seems possible.You have write an adapter to achieve the things. Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28054985/flatten-nested-object-into-target-object-with-gson) [link2](https://github.com/Tishka17/gson-flatten)